# draw a 8 X 8 table with images (game board) with javascript

Tags: javascript, web

hello I am new to web development.
I am trying to make 8X8 table with each cell appended to an image.
 i would like to know why the image would not append to the cell

this should result something like :
" "ABCDEFGH
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

here is the code

```
function drawGame(){    
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute('style','float:left');
    var startRow = table.insertRow(0);
    var srcW="./assets/img/disk-w.png";
    var srcB="./assets/img/disk-b.png";
    var srcE="./assets/img/disk-e.png";
                         //'<td><img src="./assets/img/disk-b.png" alt="B" class="disk-black" rel="'.$x.':'.$y.'" /></td>'; break;
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    //img.src = "link to image here";
    //x.appendChild(img);
    var row;
    var text = document.createTextNode("&nbsp;");
    var cell = startRow.insertCell(0);
    cell.setAttribute('class','board-corner');
    var c = 'A'.charCodeAt();
    for(j=0; j<8; j++){
        text = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(c++));
        cell = startRow.insertCell(j+1);

        cell.appendChild(text);

    }
    for(y=1;y<=8;y++)
    {

        row=table.insertRow(y);
        text = document.createTextNode(y);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.appendChild(text);
        for(x=0;x<8;x++)
        {
            img.src = srcE;
            cell = row.insertCell(x+1);
            cell.appendChild(img);
            cell.setAttribute('class','disk-empty');
            cell.setAttribute('alt','e');

        }

    }
document.getElementById("gameDiv").appendChild(table);
}
```

thank you for your time

Comment: If you add the html (and the rest of the script if there is more) will be easier

Comment: this is the full code of the function, I don't know if i need to add something. the .insertcell(0) inserts a number in the beginning of each row. so it should result something like: row1:" "ABCDEFGH row two 1...... row 3: 2......

Comment: Sorry @user3503716, I edited my comment when I realize it could be confusing. I tried to mean that you could make a jsfiddle and/or post the html also so otrhers can try to figure out what is happening. It's nice if you also explain what you are trying to achieve (even if it could be guessed from the code) ...I don't know wht are you getting now, it could be lot of things: you didn't upload the images to the site, wrong selector (gamediv), etc...

Comment: ...but the only and most interesting thing is inside your comment in the code, there is where I realized the "." before your images. Why? Maybe that's your answer... next time take a look to the source code in your browser ;) (and the log)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, unfortunately I don't have the right to add images what I am getting is a table like i wanted (a board game) with the css layout that i want. the only thing that i don't get is the images in the cells

Comment: Don't worry about the images and also take a look to http://jsfiddle.net/ You can place there a "play with it" with your code. Hope the comment before gives you a clue to the solution.

Comment: thank you, I think that i can't use the "." before the link to the img I have to search for the correct way. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly address your code, but you might look at assigning a css class to each square on the grid corresponding to the image you're wanting to put on it. Then use a css file to set the background of the element equal to your image. Then you can use your browser's dev tools (F12 in chrome/firefox) to trouble shoot your links if they still arent't showing up.